# Update a table column from the column of another table in MsAccess

Tags: sql, sql-update, ms-access-2010

In Ms Access 2010 I have two identical tables, say A and B.

The structure of each table is

```
key | text_column1 | text_column2
```

I have to update the rows of table A such that if for a given row in A the two text columns are empty, then the value from table B must be given.

Looking [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506728/update-column-with-another-value-from-the-same-table), I tried

```
UPDATE  A as a
SET a.text_column1 = (SELECT b.text_column1 FROM B AS b WHERE b.key = a.key),
a.text_column2 = (SELECT b.text_column2 FROM B AS b WHERE b.key = a.key)
WHERE a.text_column1 IS NULL and a.text_column2
```

Needless to say that the previous query doesn't work. I got [error 3073 (2010)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760740.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Access's `UPDATE .. JOIN` syntax:

```
UPDATE  A as a
        INNER JOIN B as b
            ON a.Key = b.Key
SET     a.text_column1 = b.text_column1,
        a.text_column2 = b.text_column2
WHERE   a.text_column1 IS NULL
AND     a.text_column2 IS NULL;
```

Another option is to use [`Dlookup`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx):

```
UPDATE  A
SET     text_column1 = Dlookup("text_column1", "B", "Key = "& A.Key),
        text_column2 = Dlookup("text_column2", "B", "Key = "& A.Key)
WHERE   a.text_column1 IS NULL
AND     a.text_column2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: The first solution works very well! I didn't tried `DLOOKUP`.

Comment: @mat_boy FYI, the edit you made does not make any difference. It works fine without the table aliases. Furthermore you are giving a table an alias that is the same as it's name - it's kind of like saying, "Hi my name is Gareth, but you can call me Gareth".

Comment: I do agree with you! Clearly my table name are not `A` and `B` :) So, I added aliasing to avoid confusion between lower/upper cases. Suppose that one wants to apply the above lines in another context. Aliasing may help him to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE  A
SET A.text_column1 = (SELECT b.text_column1 FROM B AS b WHERE b.key = A.key),
A.text_column2 = (SELECT b.text_column2 FROM B AS b WHERE b.key = A.key)
WHERE A.text_column1 IS NULL and A.text_column2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: This will work in a lot of DBMS, but this won't work in Access.

Comment: @GarethD: Have you tried it and can you please justify your reason in saying so.

Comment: Yes I have tried it (on 2007 version at least) - see screenshot in my answer. I don't know the exact reason that Access has not implemented this syntax, or why it has these limitations. I just know that it does.